# How can I make a useful check if 2D-coordinates are in a circle and write them

Tags: c, geometry

I want to check if certain 2D-Coordinates are outside various circles. I have already set up the cirlce check, but I also wnt to write only the coordinates outsode the circle. I cant seem to get it right.

I have already tried an if-loop, but for all circles, the coordintes are written multiple times. The 2D-Coordinates and the Circle Center coordinates are give in structures. I want to print ot an output file.

```
//Function for check if another point is in radius around point p

bool circle_check( double xpoint, double ypoint, double x_center, double    y_center, double diameter, int holenumber) {
                if ( ( ( (xpoint-x_center)*(xpoint-x_center) ) + ( (ypoint-y_center)*(ypoint-y_center) ) ) <= (diameter*diameter/4) ) {
                    printf ("Found needle inside hole no. %d with x,y: %.0lf,%.0lf\n", holenbumber+1, xpoint, ypoint);
                    fprintf(logfile, "Found needle inside hole no. %d with x,y: %.0lf,%.0lf\n", holenbumber+1, xpoint, ypoint);
                   return true;}
                else {
                    return false;}
```

Here is the writing condition:

```
for (i=0;i<number_points;i++){

    for (k=0;k<=number_circles;k++){

    if (circle_check( new_coord[i].xcoord, new_coord[i].ycoord, holes[k].xhcoord, holes[k].yhcoord, holes[k].diamh, k) == false){
        fprintf( result, "%.0lf\t%.0lf\n", new_coord[i].xcoord, new_coord[i].ycoord);
                      }
                  }
             }
         }
```

With this code the coordinates are written k-times and not only once.

Comment: Initialise a flag to `0` inside the outer loop. If the point is within any circle, set the flag. After the loop, print the result once. Your `printf` is inside the loop. You can also make it more efficient by breaking out of the loop as soon as you find any circle which contains the point being tested. Note too that you are outputting the result twice anyway: once to `logfile` and once to `result`.

Comment: Do you have `number_circles` circles or `number_circles+1`  circles?  `for (k=0;k<=number_circles;k++)` is suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check all the circles and consolidate the checks into a single decision before writing anything. If you only want points that are outside of all the circles, you could do:

```
for (i=0;i<number_points;i++) {
    bool is_inside_any_circle = false;
    for (k=0;k<=number_circles;k++) {
        is_inside_any_circle = is_inside_any_circle || circle_check( new_coord[i].xcoord, new_coord[i].ycoord, holes[k].xhcoord, holes[k].yhcoord, holes[k].diamh, k);
    }
    if(!is_inside_any_circle)
        fprintf( result, "%.0lf\t%.0lf\n", new_coord[i].xcoord, new_coord[i].ycoord);
 }
```